# How to reverse the F keys default functionality

Tags: macos, keyboard

I am newbie Mac user and I recently stumbled upon this annoying F6 problem: when I debug in Xcode or Eclipse, I must use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to run the debugger. By default, F6 is the function key to adjust the keyboard light. How can I reverse its functionality, in order to use <kbd>F6</kbd> for the debugger and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> for the keyboard light?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard tab -> check "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"

UPDATE: If you have a touch bar Mac you'll want System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard tab -> "Touch Bar shows" -> "F1, F2, etc. Keys"

UPDATE 2: in macOS Ventura (13.0) the setting has moved to System Settings... -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts... (button) -> Function Keys -> "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"

Comment: it's fantastic!!

Comment: As an added side note. If you use an external keyboard like the magic keyboard from Apple, there is an option called "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" on the same page. This should change this behaviour for external keyboards only. Might only work with Apple keyboards tho.

Comment: Sadly I had set this and forget whappen - had to find out what I did here.

Answer (score 10):

You can also invert single keys with [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

And [Paula](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/palua/id431494195?mt=12) allows you to set the global F1-F12 vs "special key" mode based on the focused application.

[image: Paula Smart Mode Preferences]